# Filter multi-entry .fasta file by partial match to id line in bash

Tags: bash, fasta

I have a .fasta file, e.g.:

```
>LTR22_Mio  ERV2    Microtus ochrogaster
tgtcacgccacctcctgcggagtctgcgtgatctctcacgtaggctgtggcacaagcttcaaggaagagt
gcccgcagagaaggtgtgtgtgctgtgcttcctgcatcggagcccttgcacttttggcattacctgctta
tgttctaaggaatacagtctggtttcttctggaagggaagatagtatgtttaagtttccagagtctactg
>LTR23  ERV2    Mus Musculus
tgtcacgccacctcctgcggagtctgcgtgatctctcacgtaggctgtggcaca
>LTR_IAP    ERV2    Mus Musculus
tgtcacgccacctcctgcggagtctgcgtgatctctcacgtaggctgtggcacaagcttcaaggaagagt
gcccgcagagaaggtgtgtgtgctgtgcttcctgcatcggagcccttgcacttttggcattacctgctta
tgttctaaggaatacagtctggtttcttctggaagggaagatagtatgtttaagtttccagagtctactg
atgagacattgccatatacaggagtatatgatgctaatggaggaagatgggttaacattcaaggcaaaaa
```

I am trying to extract all headers (lines starting with `>...`) and the following text block until the next `>` that partially match to a certain pattern, in my example: `"Mus musculus"`. The ideal result would be:

```
>LTR23  ERV2    Mus Musculus
tgtcacgccacctcctgcggagtctgcgtgatctctcacgtaggctgtggcaca
>LTR_IAP    ERV2    Mus Musculus
tgtcacgccacctcctgcggagtctgcgtgatctctcacgtaggctgtggcacaagcttcaaggaagagt
gcccgcagagaaggtgtgtgtgctgtgcttcctgcatcggagcccttgcacttttggcattacctgctta
tgttctaaggaatacagtctggtttcttctggaagggaagatagtatgtttaagtttccagagtctactg
atgagacattgccatatacaggagtatatgatgctaatggaggaagatgggttaacattcaaggcaaaaa
```

I tried google for this relatively common problem and only found third-party packages for this but was hoping for a native `bash`-based solution.

I found this `grep` one-liner, but it outputs not the complete block of text following the "header" line (source: https://www.biostars.org/p/319099/):

```
grep -w -A 2 -f pattern.txt myfile.fasta --no-group-separator
```

pattern.txt:

```
Mus Musculus
```

Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: Personally I'd use Perl plus a fasta reader module from the Bioperl package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `awk` is your option, would you please try the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS = "(^|\n)>"}
   /Mus Musculus/ {
        sub(/\n$/, "");
        print ">" $0
   }
' file.fasta
```

Output:

```
>LTR23  ERV2    Mus Musculus
tgtcacgccacctcctgcggagtctgcgtgatctctcacgtaggctgtggcaca
>LTR_IAP    ERV2    Mus Musculus
tgtcacgccacctcctgcggagtctgcgtgatctctcacgtaggctgtggcacaagcttcaaggaagagt
gcccgcagagaaggtgtgtgtgctgtgcttcctgcatcggagcccttgcacttttggcattacctgctta
tgttctaaggaatacagtctggtttcttctggaagggaagatagtatgtttaagtttccagagtctactg
atgagacattgccatatacaggagtatatgatgctaatggaggaagatgggttaacattcaaggcaaaaa
```

- The statement `BEGIN {RS = "(^|\n)>"}` assigns the record separator `RS`
  to the regex meaning "the character `>` at the beginning of the file
  or after a newline" to split the file into the records which consist of
  a pair of the header line and the base line(s).
- The pattern `/Mus Musculus/` specifies the condition to print the record.
- The statement `sub(/\n$/, "")` removes the extra newline at the end of
  the file.
- The statement `print ">" $0` outputs the record prepending the character
  `>` which is lost as a record separator.